# Custom components in Markdown / MDX on Astro

Tags: markdown, astrojs, mdxjs

I would like to be able to replace the default code that Astro uses to render some Markdown elements.

For example, it would be nice that when I type :

```markdown
Some Text

![image](image.png)

---

Some other text
```

I could get

```html
<p>Some Text</p>
<div data-lightbox="true">
    <img
        class="w-2/3"
        src="image.png"
        alt="image"
    />
</div>
<div class="divider my-2" />
<p>Some other text</p>
```

So that it replaces the default code for the image and the divider.

Right now I just copy-paste the HTML / JSX code when I need it, but it would be nice to be able to have it automatically done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple with mdx as mentioned in the docs [Custom components with imported MDX](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/#custom-components-with-imported-mdx) and [custom components to html](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/#assigning-custom-components-to-html-elements) .

define your custom component, say maybe H1

H1Component.astro

```
---
const props = Astro.props;
---
<h1 {...props} class="bg-red-100"><slot /></h1>
```

---

use the above defined custom h1 component in your markdown files as below

```
import H1Component from '../components/H1Component.astro';
export const components = {h1: H1Component}

# Red Coloured Custom H1 Component

...
```

OR

wherever you render the content pass your custom components as below

```
<Content components={{...components, h1: H1Component }} />
```

---

Output

[image]

Comment: JayMGurav, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: got it, lmk if the above is helpful or if there are any other doubts

Comment: This is exaclty what I needed, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Astro’s Markdown and MDX support is powered by [remark](https://remark.js.org/). This means you can write a remark plugin to transorm certain parts of your content to fit your needs. remark is very powerful, although not always the easiest to get started with.

Markdown plugins in Astro are configured via your `astro.config.mjs` file. For example, this shows adding an existing remark plugin:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import remarkToc from 'remark-toc';

export default defineConfig({
  markdown: {
    // Applied to .md and .mdx files
    remarkPlugins: [remarkToc],
  },
});
```

An example remark plugin might look something like this

```js
import { visit } from 'unist-util-visit';

function mapImages() {
  function transformer(tree) {
    visit(tree, "image", (imageNode) => {
      // manipulate image
    });
  }
}
```

You can then import `mapImages` into `astro.config.mjs` and add it to your `remarkPlugins` array.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! What should I put inside the function in `visit` ? I tried `return <img>{imageNode}</img>;` and console logging stuff in it but it doesn't seem to do anything. I do have a message about loading a markdown plugin though ("[MDX] Now inheriting remark and rehype plugins from "markdown" config.
If you applied a plugin to both your Markdown and MDX configs, we suggest removing the duplicate MDX entry.")